# How do I make my Perl tests execute in a given order?

Tags: perl, testing

When I use `Test::Class` and `Test::More` to do system testing, it seems that the test cases execute in parallel.  My tests, however, have dependencies between them such that I would like to have tests executive in series.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of the module  Test::Unit::TestCase  in the NOTES section at the bottom:

If you need to specify the test order, you can do one of the following:

- Set @TESTS

  our @TESTS = qw(my_test my_test_2);

  This is the simplest, and recommended way.
- Override the list_tests() method

  to return an ordered list of methodnames
- Provide a suite() method

  which returns a Test::Unit::TestSuite.

My personal 2 cents:
Using `Test::Class` instead of `Test::Unit::TestCase` is probably a better alternative. The module documentation even has a good [introduction](http://search.cpan.org/~adie/Test-Class-0.38/lib/Test/Class.pm#INTRODUCTION), and a useful section on ["Confused Junit Users"](http://search.cpan.org/~adie/Test-Class-0.38/lib/Test/Class.pm#HELP_FOR_CONFUSED_JUNIT_USERS) which you should be reading even if you keep using  Test::Unit::TestCase .

Comment: The OP might also want to take a look at Test::Routine if they're a Moose user - it's rather nice.

Comment: i am sorry that i post wrong perl test module. yes, I use the Test::Class, and Test::More such modules to do my testcases. it seems that there is not any info teaching me how to do my testcases in sequential. the problem is i need one testcase's returned value to be used for the following testcases.

Answer (score 3):

[Test::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~adie/Test-Class-0.38/lib/Test/Class.pm#RUNNING_ORDER_OF_METHODS) executes its tests in alphabetic order. It's annoying, but you can name your test subroutines in a way that they will be executed in the proper order. Are you sure they are running in parallel? Are you possibly using [prove](http://perldoc.perl.org/prove.html) on more than one file with a `--jobs` flag?